# "ERR unknown command 'memory', with args beginning with: USAGE" with Jedis and AWS ElastiCache

Tags: java, redis, amazon-elasticache, jedis

While using `memoryUsage(key)` method of Jedis i am getting this following error
"errorMessage": "ERR unknown command 'memory', with args beginning with: USAGE"
is it possible that this method is not allowed on AWS ElastiCache

Expected behavior
I should retrieve the memory used by key-value in cache

Actual behavior
getting this error : "ERR unknown command 'memory', with args beginning with: USAGE"

Steps to reproduce:

```
public Long getValueSize(String hashKey, Jedis jedis) {
  log.info("Request received to get memory usage from redis for key {}", hashKey);
  byte[] serializeKey = kryo.serialize(hashKey);
  return jedis.memoryUsage(serializeKey);
}
```

i am using JedisPool from which i am taking a Jedis instance to perform this action.

Redis / Jedis Configuration
Jedis library version: 5.1.2
ElastiCache version: 7.1.0
Java version: 17

When i tried it locally with dockerized environment, where my java client was running as a lambda inside a docker container and redis instance was also running in a container at that time i am not getting such error and obtaining the expected result and on aws environment where i have ElastiCache instead of Redis i am getting this error as a response.

I believe it might be case that this particular method is not compatible with AWS ElastiCache but i am not sure of it as i am using it first time.

Thanks in advance :)